# Using jquery with MVC4 - DateTimePicker

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datetimepicker

I'm trying to implement a simple date time picker in an MVC4 application but i can't get it working. I'm sure the mistake is a silly one but i can't spot it.

This is my view

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate)
</div>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#StartDate').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

The text box shows but it doesn't pop up a datetime picker like I expect it to, what am I missing?

Comment: Have you included jquery.ui.css ??

Comment: no need to add datepicker.js and css, Only add jquery.ui.css

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the textbox?

Comment: I have added this but it still doesn't work, thanks for the comment though!

Comment: Yup @stovroz, nothing comes up

Comment: This seems to work fine here- https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lmh8Vm

Comment: Interesting @Manoz, thanks for that! I've played around with it and i have commented out 
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
these lines from the shared layout and now it works...

Comment: Does that mean something in the other scripts file was interfering with the jquery?

Comment: Yes, you were using jQuery twice if bundling was there. The one from the bundle and your own source. If you want to use both in any case then use jQuery conflicts.

Comment: You're including the jquery files twice if they're in your view above and also presumably included in the bundles in the layout. Check App_Start/BundleConfig.cs.

Comment: I think i've got it. Thanks for all the help!